# Make UIButton accessible in Interface Builder

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, interface-builder, ibdesignable

I'm working on a little project which adds a little bar on the bottom of the screen, similar to `UITabBar` (see screenshot below). It's an `@IBDesignable` class. The blue boxes you can see are buttons with placeholder images. Now my question is, can I somehow open up these buttons to the IB as well? Like when I click one of the boxes I get the attribute inspector for that specific button?
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Well, if every button has it's own xib, you can edit them there.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I miss understood the question. No you can't have a UIButton as an attribute in the interface builder. I believe @IBInspectable only supports a certain group of types.

These are the types that I know, maybe there are more types.

- Int
- CGFloat
- Double
- String
- Bool
- CGPoint
- CGSize
- CGRect
- UIColor
- UIImage

However, you can do something like the example below and apply that to other properties:

```
@IBDesignable class CustomTabBar: UITabBar {
    var button1: CustomButton!
    var button2: CustomButton!
    var button3: CustomButton!

    @IBInspectable var button1Title: String? {
        get {
            return button1.titleLabel?.text
        } set {
            button1.setTitle(newValue, for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```